# Procedimiento almacenado en MySQL no devuelve los números no primos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, revisión-de-código, depuración

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL que debe darme los números no primos del número que yo introduzca, y los almacene en una variable para mostrarla como parámetro de salida.

El problema que tengo es que la salida, me muestra todos los números. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
use bdprueba;
DELIMITER //
create procedure listarprimos (IN numeroalistar int, OUT sucesion varchar(255))
    begin
        declare numcontrol int default 0;
        declare control2 int default 0;
        declare contador3 int default 0;
        declare aux varchar(255) default '';
        while control2 <= numeroalistar do
            begin
                while control2 <= numcontrol  do
                    if control2 % numcontrol = 0
                     then
                        set contador3 = contador3 +1;
                        set control2 = control2 +1;
                    else
                        set control2 = control2 +1;
                    end if;
                end while;
            if contador3 > 2
                then
                    set aux = concat(aux,', ', numcontrol) ;
                    end if;
                set numcontrol = numcontrol +1;
            end;
        end while;
        set sucesion = concat('Lista: ',aux); 
        end;//
    DELIMITER ;
    call listarprimos(10, @d);
    select @d;
```

Comment: Hay muchos detalles. En la primera iteración, control2 y numcontrol ambos son 0. En MySQL creo que 0 % 0 es null (aunque debería ser indeterminado) y deberías evitar esa condición de todos modos porque el 0 no es ni primo ni compuesto.Luego, control2 y numcontrol siempre tienen el mismo valor, por lo que la condición control % numcontrol = 0 siempre será verdadera, y la variable contador3 irá incrementandose, mas no se reinicia en ningún punto, por lo que a partir de la tercera iteración, contador3>2 siempre será verdadera. Revisa estos puntos.

Comment: Una aproximación más clara, sería definir un segundo procedimiento que determine si un número es primo o no, probarlo bien y luego de estar seguro que funciona correctamente, invocarlo en este procedimiento, pasandole como parámetro el contador de las iteraciones y si es compuesto, añadirlo a la lista a imprimir.

Comment: No creo que eso tenga mucho que ver, la verdad